# How to pass list to a function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I want to store results of linear regression in list like intercept and coefficients. I have following code

```
results  = list()
intercept = list()
coeff = list()

GetLM = function(dataframe,results,intercept,coeff){
     unq_clients = as.vector(unique(dataframe$clients))
     for(i in 1:length(unq_clients)){
         new_df=dataframe[dataframe$clients ==    unq_clients[i],]
         regression= lm(a ~ b,data = new_df )
         results[[i]] = coef(regression)
         intercept[i] = results[[i]][1]
         coeff[i]=results[[i]][2]
     }
}
```

But nothing is getting stored in list when I call the function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why is a `return()` statement missing in your function. Without that, no additions made to results will be reflected outside the scope of function. add something like `return(list(results, intercept, coeff))` to the end of function

Comment: and also avoid using a `for` loop . try something like `lapply()`

Answer (score 0):

I feel you programmed in a non R way this function. Why would you need `results`, `intercept` and `coeff` as arguments to `GetLM`? Instead, make the function return a list with these variables:

```
GetLM <- function(dataframe){
     unq_clients <- as.vector(unique(dataframe$clients))
     for(i in 1:length(unq_clients)){
         new_df <- dataframe[dataframe$clients == unq_clients[i],]
         regression <- lm(a~b,data = new_df )
         results <- coef(regression)
         intercept[i] <- results[[i]][1]
         coeff[i] <- results[[i]][2]
     }
     return(list(results = results, intercept = intercept, coeff = coeff))
}
```

So that now you can do:

```
reslist <- GetLM(dataframe = your_data_frame)
results <- reslist$results
intercept <- reslist$intercept
coeff <- reslist$coeff
```

Answer (score 0):

you can perfectly continue with your own code, just need to add a `return()` statement as I have mentioned in the comments.

Here I'm using `lapply()` to replace the `for` loop and also making it more generalised such that even if your model has more than 1 independent , you can extract them in a better way.

Note : I'm using `mtcars` to explain since you didn't share any data with us

```
unq_cyl = as.vector(unique(mtcars$cyl)) # 3 unique values
results <- lapply(seq_along(unq_cyl), function(x) {
                                    new_df = mtcars[mtcars$cyl == unq_cyl[x],]
                                    regression= lm(mpg ~ disp + wt,data = new_df )
                                    results=coef(regression)
                                    results})

intercept <- sapply(results, FUN = function(i) i[names(i) %in% "(Intercept)"])
coeff <- sapply(results, FUN = function(i) i[!(names(i) %in% "(Intercept)")])


results
#[[1]]
#(Intercept)        disp          wt 
#28.18834771  0.01914227 -3.83509580 
#
#[[2]]
#(Intercept)        disp          wt 
# 41.1350198  -0.1224733  -0.6978035 
#
#[[3]]
# (Intercept)         disp           wt 
#24.077855175 -0.002511735 -2.023137804 

intercept
#(Intercept) (Intercept) (Intercept) 
#   28.18835    41.13502    24.07786 
coeff
#            [,1]       [,2]         [,3]
#disp  0.01914227 -0.1224733 -0.002511735
#wt   -3.83509580 -0.6978035 -2.023137804
```